# Variable can only be null shows eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have wriiten a method like this

```
public ArrayList<T> GetDoctorDetail(String name)
{
    if (name!=null || !name.isEmpty() || name!="")
    {
        //Statements
    }
}
```

but in eclipse !name by underline with a yellow line show 
       Null pointer access: The variable name can only be null at this location.

why? and what is the solution.

Comment: You can also remove the last condition as isEmpty() checks for ""

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `name` is non-null, the conditional `||` operator won't evaluate the second operand at all. So the *only* case in which the second operand can be evaluated is when `name` is null, in which case it will throw.

I suspect you want

```
if (name != null && !name.isEmpty())
{
    // Use name
}
```

Or possibly:

```
if (name == null || name.isEmpty())
{
    // Show an error message
}
```

Note that comparing strings with `==` and `!=` is *also* almost always the wrong thing to do, as it compares *references*. You would normally use `equals` instead. Not only that, but it would be useless anyway here - it could only be equal to "" if it's empty, so it's the exact same condition as the second operand.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the oR condition will only fail if name = null. Hence the second part will throw a null pointer exception.

The correct way to write that condition is

```
if (name!=null && (!name.isEmpty() || name!=""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
   // Now the name variable has valid content
}
```

*Note* - The logic is always much easier to understand if you create "positive" checks:

```
if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
   // Now name is either null or empty
} else {
   // Now the name has valid content
}
```

Try to avoid conditions that check for "negative" states, like "is not null" and "is not empty". They're nothing but brain twisters ;)